# Quicksight: Aggregation Over Last Day of Month

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I am working on a chart bar that the x-axis is a date aggregated by month. ¿Is is posible to aggregate by day but only show the last day of each month using a filter o by other way? Other possibility i see is to create a calculated field to show the value for the last day of the aggregated period but i have not been able to do it ¿Is it posible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally solve it like this using the posted formulas:

```
parseDate
(
concat
(
toString(extract("YYYY",addDateTime(1,"DD",addDateTime(1,"MM",truncDate("MM",date)))))
,"-"
,toString(extract("MM",addDateTime(1,"DD",addDateTime(1,"MM",truncDate("MM",date)))))
,"-"
,toString(extract("DD",addDateTime(-1,"DD",addDateTime(1,"MM",truncDate("MM",date)))))
)
,'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

And because current month have not ended so i don't have data for the the last day i use an ifelse like this:

```
ifelse(
parseDate(
concat(
toString(extract("YYYY",addDateTime(-1,"DD",addDateTime(1,"MM",truncDate("MM",date)))))
,"-"
,toString(extract("MM",addDateTime(-1,"DD",addDateTime(1,"MM",truncDate("MM",date)))))
,"-"
,toString(extract("DD",addDateTime(-1,"DD",addDateTime(1,"MM",truncDate("MM",date))))))
,'yyyy-MM-dd') 
>= now()
,addDateTime(-1,"DD",now())
,parseDate(concat(toString(extract("YYYY",addDateTime(-1,"DD",addDateTime(1,"MM",truncDate("MM",date)))))
,"-"
,toString(extract("MM",addDateTime(-1,"DD",addDateTime(1,"MM",truncDate("MM",date)))))
,"-"
,toString(extract("DD",addDateTime(-1,"DD",addDateTime(1,"MM",truncDate("MM",date)))))
)
,'yyyy-MM-dd')
)
```

And finally i created de following calculated field:

```
sumIf(base,formatDate(date,'yyyy-MM-dd') = formatDate({fecha_last_day},'yyyy-MM-dd'))
```

The result:

[The value related to the last day for each month, and for current month the last day with able data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhWjR.png)

Answer (score 1):

> calculated field to show the value for the last day of the aggregated period but i have not been able to do it. Is it posible?

Using the previous answer, I used this formula in Quicksight calculated field to get the figure for 'last day of the current month'. You can change now() to get the last day of another period.

```
extract("DD",addDateTime(-1,"DD",addDateTime(1,"MM",truncDate("MM",now()))))
```

Comment: Thanks! I used your formula to get to my answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do to provide the best guidance.

If I had to write an expression to calculate last day of the month, I would

1. Use truncDate function to extract month and year information from the date
2. Add 1 to the month, unless it is December
3. Get first day of the month (which always has 1 as the day)
4. Use addDateTime to subtract one day

For example, given a date 02/19/20 (in the format MM/DD/YYYY).
02 is the month number
20 is the year number
The following month is 03
Beginning of that month is 03/01/20
Last day of the previous month will be 02/29/20 which I will get by subtracting a day from March 1st.